# Passing Date as a parameter to a subreport/another report to use as a parameter

Tags: reporting-services, subreport

I have two reports. The first report selects a report type from a dropdownbox and accepts from/to dates and when click on the view report - lists customer names for this report type.

When you click on the `customername`, the second report is called (action) passing 3 parameters - `customername`, `datefrom`, and `dateto` as parameters to be used in the second report.

When I run each report individually, both run fine. When I run the first report (select report type, select `datefrom`/`dateto`), this report lists all customer names for this report type. When I click on the `customername`, I am getting an error:

> 'The value provided for the report parameter 'reportdatefrom' is not
>   valid for its type' (rsReportParameterTypeMismatch)

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like format(Parameters!reportdatefrom.Value,"YYYYMMDD") to force the value into a canonical string before passing it to the subreport.

SSRS sometimes has issues w/ date times. The URL addressability means that all parameter values get converted to strings anyhow, but default conversion rules can run differ between components. One component will generate a date time literal that another component can't read. Usually this is due to non-US regional settings.

Anyhow, to get around this, just convert dates to string literals in ODBC canonical form before passing them around.

Comment: String expression should be in the right format: format(Parameters!reportdatefrom.Value,"yyyyMMdd")  (notice lower case for year and day). Had similar problem and following expression worked in my report: =Format(Parameters!reportdatefrom.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy")

Answer (score 0):

It depends too on how you're passing the URL into the sub-report.

If you're passing it via the SubReport object in your main report, and the Action property via the URL option:

[image]

I suggest you create the URL string and add to it the Field references you require to fulfill the subreport's parameter requirements.

ie

```
="http://serverXXXX/ReportServer?/FernandoReports/rptTET&rs:Command=Render&rc:toolbar=false&wsTETID=" + Fields!TETID.Value.ToString()
```

That way you're forcing SSRS to render the entire field value as one string with the correct value from the Fields table.

Answer (score 0):

Check Type Parameter in 2st report Both Parameters!From and Parameters!To are Datetime Type but i dont know what method you call 2st report but in my case I you this way

Right click on Textbox > Properties > select Action on left pane > choose Go to Report option  like this image below

[image]

Then add parameter to send to 2st report.

**Make sure Parameters!From and To (both report) are Datetime Type.**